# (UWP) How to add Content-Type header without Content-Length in GET request

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, http-headers, httprequest

I'm dealing with a third-party API who's calls require the Content-Type header on GET method requests, but return an error response when the header collection includes "Content-Length". The only way to add the Content-Type header is to add a class that inherits/implements the IHttpContent interface (I was using HttpStringContent with string.empty as the string content). The problem, is that adding a blank HttpStringContent adds ContentLength. Even though the value of that header is '0', their server gets super angry. Content-Length doesn't show up in the header collection while i'm debugging, but when i run my application through Postman or Burp Proxy, the Content-Length header is there. I've tried blindly using .Remove to get rid of the Content-Length header but that doesn't work.

I've seen StackOverflow questions about adding Content-Length, but that's not what i need/want. Is there any way to have the Content-Type header in a GET request, **without** having the Content-Length header? Or.... is there a way to remove the Content-Length header? I've tried creating my own content class that implements IHttpContent, but i'm getting stuck with the implementation of IAsyncOperationWithProgress.

I understand this isn't standard, which is why i'm having so much difficulty with this. I've also tried Flurl which also didn't add the Content-Type header.

**TL;DR: Content-Type (application/json) is mandatory, and Content-Length results (even though it's 0) in API errors. How do i add Content-Type to Windows.Web.Http.HttpRequestMessage/HttpClient without Content-Length?**

EDIT: for clarification this is a UWP application

Answer (score 3):

As you're aware, you're needing to do something non-standard, so I present a non-standard solution to get this done.

You've likely tried `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add()` and `client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation()` without success. You can use reflection to evil your way into `HttpRequestHeaders` to modify the validation behavior.

```
static void AllowInvalidRequestHeader(string header)
{
    var headerType = typeof(HttpRequestHeaders);

    var field = headerType
        .GetField("invalidHeaders", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | 
                                    System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static) ?? 
                headerType
        .GetField("s_invalidHeaders", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | 
                                      System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static);

    if (field == null) return;

    var invalidFields = (HashSet<string>)field.GetValue(null);

    invalidFields.Remove(header);
}
```

In application initialization, call `AllowInvalidRequestHeader("Content-Type")` once, and initialize `HttpClient` instances with this:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
```

In a simple server side page that echos have request headers, I get back:

```
<div class="row">
    <p>Connection: Keep-Alive</p>
    <p>Content-Type: application/json</p>
    <p>Host: localhost:52975</p>
    <p>MS-ASPNETCORE-TOKEN: de3a3a58-eccc-407b-b5f7-9a6663631587</p>
    <p>X-Original-Proto: http</p>
    <p>X-Original-For: 127.0.0.1:53362</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Meh.... :( I'm still getting

`A method was called at an unexpected time.

Misused header name. Make sure request headers are used with HttpRequestMessage, response headers with HttpResponseMessage, and content headers with HttpContent objects.`

on the Add method

Comment: Can confirm that `AllowInvalidRequestHeader` _does_ actually remove "Content-Type" from the collection.

Comment: for clarification this is a UWP application. There were no exceptions in the reflection method, but the instance of HttpClient still refused to add Content-Type

Comment: I realized that after reviewing what you advised me. I don't have a convenient way of setting up a UWP dev environment right now, so I can't provide additional sure advice on how to proceed.

Comment: Reflection seemingly doesn't work with UWP (COM objects). Think i remember reading something about an issue with COM objects at runtime. I created my own custom workaround