# How to set content-md5 header in GET method using HttpClient?

Tags: c#, .net, dotnet-httpclient

I have the following code to set content-md5 in my GET method request using [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.6.2)

```
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("content-md5", "value");
```

I cannot use [HttpRequestMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httprequestmessage?view=netframework-4.6.2) content to set it because it's not a POST method. When using [Postman](https://www.postman.com/) it works like a charm but fails when using `HttpClient.GetAsync`.
Client request a hmac to the server as follows

`{
    "content_to_hash": "my content"
}`

The server will give response like this

`{
    "content_md5": "88af7ceab9fdafb76xxxxx",
    "date": "Sat, 02 May 2020 00:13:16 +0700",
    "hmac_value": "WfHgFyT792IENmK8Mqz9LysmP8ftOP00qA="
}`

Now I have to access a GET request using that hmac where it's the problem because I cannot set in httpClient GET request header.

Here's the image

[image]

Comment: Eh? Sorry, why can't you set the Content-MD5 on the Content?

Comment: GET method has no content

Comment: So why do you want to set Content-MD5? ([Content-MD5](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/http-the-definitive/1565925092/re17.html): _"The Content-MD5 header is used by servers to provide a message-integrity check for the message body. "_)

Comment: The api is not mine. I need to set it because the api requires it. You can see the image

Comment: OK. What are you supposed to set for `Content-MD5` in the case that there is no content? Always `d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e` (MD5 of `string.Empty`)?

Comment: Why can postman do it?

Comment: Because Postman doesn't validate the parameters you send?

Comment: All I need i to set it like postman do, without validation but it fails.

Comment: Do you definitely need `Content-MD5`? Since `Content-MD5` without any content is meaningless (what would it be a hash of? nothing?).

Comment: Is Content-MD5 being used in an unconventional way such that it isn't a hash of the Content, but of the request or something?

Comment: I think the image I attached described everything. Without content-md5 header the request fails.

Comment: And I do want to make this as clear as I possibly can for you: `Content-MD5` represents a hash of the request body. If there is no request body, there is nothing to hash.

Comment: Anyway, it seems that [Content-MD5](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/aaca53b025f41ab638466b1efe569df314f689ea/System/net/System/Net/Http/Headers/HttpContentHeaders.cs#L162) is added to a list of "invalid headers" which is then set on the request-level [header collection](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/aaca53b025f41ab638466b1efe569df314f689ea/System/net/System/Net/Http/Headers/HttpHeaders.cs#L367)

Comment: This causes causes [TryCheckHeaderName](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/aaca53b025f41ab638466b1efe569df314f689ea/System/net/System/Net/Http/Headers/HttpHeaders.cs#L1145) to return `false` and in turn [`TryAddWithoutValidation` returns false](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/aaca53b025f41ab638466b1efe569df314f689ea/System/net/System/Net/Http/Headers/HttpHeaders.cs#L105). Your only hope might be to replace `HttpRequestHeaders` with your own.

Answer (score 0):

From reading the `HttpClient` and related source code, there's no way you can get around this and add the header to the actual request object headers. There is an internal list of invalid headers, which includes any `Content-*` headers. It has to be on a content object.

Therefore, my suggest solution is to create your own content object:

```
public class NoContentMd5 : HttpContent
{
    protected override Task SerializeToStreamAsync(Stream stream, TransportContext context)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    protected override bool TryComputeLength(out long length)
    {
        length = 0;
        return false;
    }

    public NoContentMd5(byte[] contentMd5)
    {
        this.Headers.ContentMD5 = contentMd5;
    }

    public NoContentMd5(string contentMd5)
    {
        this.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-MD5", contentMd5);
    }
}
```

This will add the `Content-MD5` header with a value of your choosing, but the request won't contain a body.

The next problem you'll encounter is that you're trying to make a GET request with content, which isn't supported by the helper `client.GetAsync(...)` method. You'll have to make your own request object and use `client.SendAsync(...)` instead:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "https://localhost/my/test/uri");
request.Content = new NoContentMd5("d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e ");
var result = await client.SendAsync(request);
```

Note that if you have your Content-MD5 hash as bytes, I've also added a constructor to `NoContentMd5` for `byte[]` too.

The only potential issue with this is that it includes a `Content-Length: 0` header. Hopefully that's OK with the API you're working with.

There's an alternative solution described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49602533/3181933) to question with a similar issue. I'd argue against using it since is vulnerable to changes in the implementation details of `HttpRequestHeaders` (because it uses reflection, so if MS change the code, it might break) .

Comment: Cannot send a content-body with this verb-type.

Comment: Anyway, if my answer doesn't solve the problem, then the answer I linked to using reflection is probably your only option if you want to continue using `HttpClient`.

Answer (score -1):

Aside from the fact that it's not considered good practice to send a body with GET request (see [HTTP GET with request body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body)), you can try this:

```cs
using (var content = new StringContent(string.Empty))
using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage
{
    Method = HttpMethod.Get,
    RequestUri = new Uri("http://localhost"),
    Content = content
})
{
    request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("content-md5", "value");;
    using (var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request))
    {
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

The proper way would be to set the `ContentMD5` property on the `HttpContentHeaders`, for example:

```cs
content.Headers.ContentMD5 = Convert.FromBase64String(hashString);
```

But as you pointed out in the comments, trying to send content in a GET request causes an error.

Comment: Error. Cannot send a content-body with this vert-type.

Comment: Removing content makes the request successfully sent but the `content-md5` header is still not set

Comment: As I explained in the comments, `TryAddWithoutValidation` returns `false` because `Content-MD5` isn't an allowed non-content header. I've also supplied necessary links to the sections of Microsoft's code so that you can verify this yourself.